# How can I continue Rx chain different ways based on the property?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a method where based on Flowable data value I need to continue RX chain different ways .
what I mean is that if the isOnline property of data object is true then I need to call scan(initial,selector) but if it is false then I need to call scan(selector)

```
 @NotNull
    public Flowable<Data> initialCall(
            @NotNull Flowable<Info> info, Data initial) {
        return  info
                .map()
                .switchMap(it -> call(Flowable.just(it),initial, it.isOnline));
    }



   private Flowable<Data> call (
            Flowable<A> a, 
            Data initial, boolean isOnline
    ) {
        return Flowable.combineLatest(
                a,
                b,
                (a, b) -> {
                    return ....;
                })
                .switchMap()
    ///here based on the Data isOnline property I need to call either 
    ///scan(initial, selector) or scan(selector) and then continue.... 
                .map()
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .toObservable()
                .compose()
                .compose()
                .toFlowable(BUFFER)
    }
```

Comment: Should both `scan` return the same return type?

Comment: Yes the same return type

Comment: Could you please give an example, how the signature of both scans look? switchMap returns a 'Data' and scan with selector mapps from (data, data) -> data, but your initial value is of type C. This will not work, because scan(c, (prev, curr) -> { returns type c }). This is only possible, when C is of type Data. Could you please clearify?

Comment: Sorry I just tried to simplify the code and made mistakes. yes initial is type of Data

Comment: I also want to mention that the property that based on it should scan (initial, selector) or scan() should be could we have that property when we are calling call method as well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this, what you want? Based on `isOnline` a `scan`-operator is applied with or without a `seed` value.

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.BackpressureStrategy;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.FlowableTransformer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class So65349760 {
  private static <C extends Data> FlowableTransformer<Data, Data> scan(
      Boolean isOnline, C initialValue) {
    if (isOnline) {
      return upstream -> {
        return upstream.scan(
            initialValue,
            (prev, current) -> {
              return new Data();
            });
      };
    } else {
      return upstream -> upstream.scan((prev, current) -> new Data());
    }
  }

  @Test
  void so65349760() {
    Flowable<Integer> a = Flowable.fromCallable(() -> 1);
    Flowable<String> b = Flowable.fromCallable(() -> "42");

    Data seed = new Data();

    call(a, b, seed, false).test().assertValueCount(1);
    call(a, b, seed, true).test().assertValueCount(2);
  }

  private <A, B, C extends Data> Flowable<Data> call(
      Flowable<A> a, Flowable<B> b, C init, boolean isOnline) {
    return Flowable.combineLatest(a, b, (v1, v2) -> 42)
        .switchMap(integer -> Flowable.just(new Data()))
        .compose(scan(isOnline, init))
        .map(d -> d)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .toObservable()
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
  }

  private static class Data {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hans Wurst, 
As I understand scan is method that you have defined, but I am. not sure where upstream comes from ? 
I understand that it is stream that we have after switchmap but don't understand how we have access in scan ?

Comment: Upstream is provided by the `compose`. Just look at the interface definition `FlowableTransformer<@NonNull Upstream, @NonNull Downstream> { Publisher<Downstream> apply(@NonNull Flowable<Upstream> upstream) }`. The `scan` method implements the Transformer via a lambda. You could also use a antonymous class implementation. `Flowable#compose` gives you the freedom to extract operators to another place and apply them to any matching `Flowable`. Further reading: https://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/

Comment: Thanks so much, You are really skilful in Rx.

Comment: I have one more question it is not in this scope of the question ,but in the article you shared it talks about flatmap vs  compose , but flatmap as input takes simple Data but compose transforms Flowable of Data , yes ? the reason I am interested you can see in the code I have shared in initialCall I have switchmap as flatmap doesn't keep order I used switchmap I am wondering is it possible to keep order using compose ???? 
I know about concatmap and concatmapeager but they aren't beneficial to use .

Comment: sorry for the long message

Comment: Yes, `flatMap` operates on each element, `compose` operates on the whole stream. Compose gives you the oppertunity, to extract applying operators to lamda. `FlatMap` on the other hand maps and merges the inner stream, returned from given lambda, into the source. It does not retain the order, because multiple streams can be flattened concurrently (default 128), when running on different threads. When the inner `Flowable` is sync, the order will be retained. Therefore compose has nothing to do with `flatMap/switchMap`. The usage, whether `switchMap` or `flatMap` must be decided by your use-case.